# Javafx label not updating after input from TextField in another scene

Tags: javafx

I have a label called test that is supposed to display the input value from TextField in the textInput class, from another scene. the value is being sent over to the main class but the label is not updating unless i click the button to go to the dialog box from textInput.

```
package javafx11;

import application.textInput;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;



public class Main extends Application {

Stage window = new Stage();
Scene s1;
Scene s2;
Label test;
String input;
Button btn;


@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws Exception {
    window=primaryStage;
    VBox layout = new VBox();
    s1= new Scene(layout,500,500);
    test = new Label("This is where your text will appear");
    btn = new Button("Click me");
    window.setTitle("Dummy program");
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    window.setScene(s1);
    window.show();
    btn.setOnAction(e -> {
    input = textInput.textInput("title", "mnessage");
    test.setText(input);
    window.setScene(s1);

        System.out.println(input);
    });

    layout.getChildren().addAll(test, btn);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

the text input class:

```
package application;

import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;  
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TextInputDialog;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Modality;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class textInput {

static String input;
public static TextField userField;

public static String textInput(String title, String message) {
    Stage window = new Stage();
    VBox layout = new VBox();
    window.setTitle(title);
    window.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    Button btn = new Button("Click me to go back");
    userField = new TextField();
    Scene s1 = new Scene(layout, 500, 500);
    window.setScene(s1);
    layout.getChildren().add(btn);
    layout.getChildren().add(userField);
    btn.setOnAction(e ->{
        input = userField.getText();
        window.close();
        System.out.println(input);
    });
    layout.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    window.show();
    return input;

}

}
```

I tried googling it but i cant really seem to understand the solution provided by others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its all good, figured it out after tinkering with it a little longer.

in the main class, i had to change window.show(); to window.showAndWait();